# How do I access the PHI 5.3 corpus through CLTK?

Tags: resource-request, text-corpus, packhum-corpus

CLTK (the Classical Languages ToolKit) seems to contain several tools to work with the Packhum Latin corpus. However, the actual setup process seems to require the use of several different tools, none of which fully integrate with the NLTK CorpusReader interface.

So—what is the actual process of setting up the PHI corpus for use with CLTK? What steps are involved?

Comment: (I'm experimenting with this myself, and will hopefully be able to provide a good answer sometime soon if nobody else has one.)